# Copy the value in a range of cells to another cell if only one cell in the range has a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of cells M4:M18. In that range of cells is a formula referencing another table, there will only be one date in this range of cells. I'm trying to get that one date to populate into cell H12. This is the formula that I have in H12:

=IF(COUNTA(M4:M18)=1,INDEX(M4:M18,MATCH("*",M4:M18,0)),"")

I've also tried:

=IF(COUNTIF(M4:M18,"?")=1,INDEX(M4:M18,MATCH("?",M4:M18,0)),"")

This formula returns a black cell in H12. I read a previous post regarding this same issue, but I can't seem to get it to work. The first cell in this range could be empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

M4:M18 ='Step 2 Triage_Tbl'!$Q3 and are formatted as m/d/yy;;""

[and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMkIr.png)

Comment: It depends.......are *M4:M18* filled with formulas and only one displays a non-null or does only one of the cells contain a formula??

Comment: Thanks for your response. All cells have a formula that is wrapped w/ IFERROR to show a blank cell if there is no calculation.

Comment: See below.  It can locate data that is not "blank"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say `M4:M18` is completely filled with formulas, but only one of the formulas gives data, the others, null.  This will **locate** the data:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,M4:M18<>"",0)
```

and this will **retrieve** the data:

```
=INDEX(M4:M18,MATCH(TRUE,M4:M18<>"",0))
```

[image]

This works for text or numbers or dates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it will only return the date if the date appears in M4. If its not in M4, I get 1/0/00 as a result. Seems like its only looking at the first cell and not checking the remainder of the range.

Comment: Are you sure that your formula-set is returning `Null` and not a **space character** ???

Comment: @TMusky  **I see the true problem!** The cells starting at `M4` are only formatted to **appear** empty, They are not empty!

Comment: After some testing I found that the correct date only comes up if I fill down. For example, in your sheet, C2 would show null, but if I fill down to C8 then I would see "Gold" in cell C7.

Comment: You're right, I'm using a custom format to keep the empty cells in M4:M18 from showing 1/0/00.

Comment: @TMusky  Then try:  ***=MATCH(TRUE,M4:M18<>0,0)***

Comment: Better, now instead of 1/0/00 I'm getting 1/3/00. The three is the position of the date in the range M4:M18. LOL. How would I make it return the date in the cell instead of the position?

Comment: I think I got it with this formula {=INDEX(M4:M18,MATCH(TRUE,M4:M18<>0,0))} Seems to be working out.

Comment: Great help from you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### OneDate UDF

In VBE (ALT+F11) insert a module into your worksheet and copy the code into it.

In Excel in cell `H12` type `=OneDate(M4:M18)`. You might need to format `H12` as Date if not already formatted.

```
Option Explicit

Function OneDate(CheckRange As Range) As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In CheckRange
        If IsDate(rng.Value) Then OneDate = rng.Value: Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

You might need to adjust the Macro settings for this to work:

```
File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To return only one (1) date in a range `M4:M18`, try..........

In `N2`, enter formula :

```
=IF(COUNT(M4:M18)=1,INDEX(M4:M18,MATCH(1,INDEX(0+ISNUMBER(M4:M18),0),0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: bosco_yip thank you for your response. This formula works perfectly when the range of cells do not have a formula in them. In my spreadsheet the range M4:M18 have the following formula in them:

Comment: Post your data and formula used in the range of M4:M18.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, I'm new to the site and I'm not sure how to post the formula and data correctly in the comments.

Comment: Click "Edit" under the last line of your 1st post, then writing the formula used and the screenshot using Shift+Window key (between Ctrl & Alt)+S, copy&paste to the forum